# Tkinter templating

Tags: python, tkinter

I there a website or application that lets me design my interface for tkinter before I actually code it? I want a way to be able to find out what looks good without having to mess with my code every time I want to move a button.

Answer (score 1):

There are various GUI builder applications for Tkinter:

- [Page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/)
- [Tkinter Designer](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer)
- [visualtk](https://visualtk.com) (web based)
- [pygubu](https://github.com/alejandroautalan/pygubu)

While GUI design tools are useful you will still need to alter your interface when you add UI functionality and unplanned features.

Consider following an interface first design pattern, designing your application in a vector drawing tool like adobe illustrator, affinity designer or a more focused UI design tool like [sketch](https://www.sketch.com) or [Akira](https://github.com/akiraux/Akira).

"Convert" that design into your interface either in code or using a GUI builder application mentioned above and then build your application around it.

If you have a solid understanding of how your app will function and how it will be used, the interface shouldn't need to change during development of the functionality, remember that you can use mock data to "fill" the app with dummy content if needed.

If this approach is unsuitable then maybe you should consider using something like [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/) that uses html and so can benefit from WYSIWYG or straight forward browser testing before being used in your interface.

Comment: _"there is no graphical design tool for it "_ - There is at least one that is being actively developed: [PAGE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/)

Comment: there are a couple of drag-and-drop tools for `tkinter` such as [this one](https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer), but also you can use some simple program like paint to design the GUI

Comment: @BryanOakley I was aware of some for Tk, was not aware they worked with python directly.

Comment: @Matiiss I would argue that paint is unsuitable for anything more than a quick draft because when designing interfaces you want to be able to create reusable components who's styles can be altered to test things like fonts/colours. Artboards are also fundamental in designing multiple scenes/screens and understanding UX when designing an entire application. Thanks for linking Tkinter Designer.

Comment: Yes, I agree, paint is not something one may want to use because it has basically no editing capabilities for drawn objects as they just get drawn on the screen, paint.net could be used because stuff can be put on layers and layers can be edited independently but that would be simply too much work, so yes, not paint likely